# How to fix windows 10 internet detection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet

On a windows 10 computer the network interface always has the yellow warning sign and the "no internet" tooltip, even when I switch between ethernet and wifi. Both times internet works perfect in all programs I use, but the warning is still there.

I would ignore it, but it seems that windows update is not working because of this (I am not sure and may open another question for this later), which is a problem.

What can I do to get windows to recognize it? I already ran the network troubleshooting assistants from windows 10, which i.e. already deleted all networking interfaces and re-created them.

Comment: The failure to update Windows is probably not related to the erroneous indicator. Check, though, that the values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost` are 0, rather than 1, for which update is deferred.

Comment: Is this the setting for restricted connections? This should be off (I will have a look tomorrow). For the update question I will need to do more research to ask a good question, but solving the network problem to make sure it isn't the root cause seemed useful. And I do not know what else is affected by the wrong detection.

Answer (score 0):

some time you will get get this problem just because you don't have wireless lan driver in you PC or laptop.
Just go to network adapter then search for wireless LAN and update your driver.